# Which of “press” or “depress” the enter key is the more correct choice?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, formality

I’m reading a manual right now instructing one to “press” the enter key.

However, both *press* and *depress* appear to be correct, as explained in the question [Why is the term "depressed" often used to describe a button which is pressed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21067/why-is-the-term-depressed-often-used-to-describe-a-button-which-is-pressed)

> - Click “submit” or **press** the enter key.
> - Click “submit” or **depress** the enter key.

I know that *depress* is the less commonly used one of these two, at least as a verb). But technically speaking, which is the more **correct** word to use?

Comment: I've read that question and the answers. I am not asking if the word is a valid word to use; I'm asking which one is technically the more correct one?

Comment: What [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed) have you already done? Perhaps you could include that in the question too.

Comment: You are making several assumptions here. One is that “correctness” even makes any sense here. Another is that “correctness” is not a “true-or-false” state but rather a gradable condition in which one alternative can be more correct than the second. Finally, you are assuming that there even can be a “right” answer to your question, one whose “technical correctness” (whatever that means) can be somehow demonstrated through some feat of logic or via reference to some dispositive rule-book, and that this matters. It turns out that none of these assumptions are particularly sound.